# Java: draw function graph?

Tags: java, function, graph, grid

I have problem which I want to draw a function graph with any input I key in.However I not familiar with the y-coordinate in java.I wish my graph got negative value !Does anyone know how to make it?

Comment: i think he means that if you paint in java that a negative y does not show. If thats the case just add an offset to any drawing. Example for a 100 pixel panel adding 50 to all y - coordinates gives you a graph with range from -50 to 50 give or take a pixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default origin i.e. (0,0) for java 2d graphics is at the upper left corner of your screen.

To translate it to center of your screen use the following method of Graphics class
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

translate(int x, int y)

For eg.

```
 //if your graphics object is g:

g.translate(screen_width/2, screen_height/2);

//where
//screen_width is the width of your screen
//screen_height is the height of your screen
```

Comment: Thank you ! It really work ,I just need to change the positive y to negative to get the normal coordinate !